# ORA-00979 : select distinct(concat column) not a group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00979

I am getting ORA-00979 with the following query:

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT ((colA || SUBSTR(colB, 1, 2))) AS colA 
FROM myTable 
WHERE colC='5678'
GROUP BY colA
```

I have a table called myTable which has three columns (colA, colB and colC).
I want to have in my select result: the concatenation of column colA value and the two first values of column colB. Furthermore, I want to group by my result. However, I receive an **ORA-00979** and not a group by expression error.
How can I solve this?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (not images.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you want to group, when you have no aggregation? What are you expecting the grouping you've shown to do, that the distinct (which isn't a function, by the way, so the parentheses aren't needed) doesn't already achieve for you? Without data and results it's unclear what you are trying to do, or why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may repeat the entire expression in the `GROUP BY` clause as it appears in the `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT colA || SUBSTR(colB, 1, 2) AS colA
FROM myTable
WHERE colC = '5678'
GROUP BY colA || SUBSTR(colB, 1, 2);
```

Oracle does not supporting grouping using aliases, or using `1`, `2`, etc. positional parameters.  And note that `DISTINCT` is not a SQL function.

Comment: Well, in such a case you either don't need DISTINCT (as GROUP BY will *distinct* them anyway), or you don't need GROUP BY (as DISTINCT will return *distinct* set of rows). Maybe I didn't get the idea (of what you're saying), but ... I'd say that this doesn't do what the OP wanted. What *do* they want? That's a good question too :)

Comment: You're right...the `DISTINCT` is superfluous.  And without any aggregates in the select, the `GROUP BY` is also pointless.  I will let the OP comment.  In any case, I have fixed the compiler error here.